# Extract a single instance of each entry in a large matrix

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, excel-2010, unique

In Excel 2010 I have 131 rows by the longest column up to SU. Some of the info is duplicated. I want to pull a list of one of every entry present.

Is there a formula for that?

Answer (score 0):

Not a formula, but doing a pivot on the field you want summarized is a quick way to see the distinct list.

Comment: Sure. I select the list, insert pivot table. Then select an identifying column such as name or account number and drag it to the Rows quadrant. This immediately give a quick list of the unique items. Doesn't have all the data nor drops the dupe items for the list, but is very easy/quick way to get a unique list.

Comment: @pnuts, not sure where the 515 came from, but no, was not suggesting doing an elaborate pivot table setup. Since the initial question was just asking about "pulling a list" this is something I use often when I just need a quick view of the unique values for some field. For instance I've used it when processing error logs and just need a quick list of the different types of errors being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the cell content (numbers, text etc.) a rather coarse approach may be the best available. In SV1 and copied (maybe with the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797395/1505120)) down to SV67465:

```
=OFFSET($A$1:$SU$131,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($SV$1))/COLUMNS($A$1:$SU$131)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($SV$1),COLUMNS($A$1:$SU$131)),1,1)
```

Then copy (just in case!) that entire column to say SX1 with Paste Special..., Values and then apply to that Remove Duplicates. Note that the latter has a known bug (mentioned in [“Remove Duplicates” feature does not remove all duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/572226/remove-duplicates-feature-does-not-remove-all-duplicates)) you might be unfortunate to encounter given that your matrix is of 67,465 cells of I do not know what content.